# MySQL Column Value Pivot

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a MySQL InnoDB table laid out like so:
id (int), run_id (int), element_name (varchar), value (text), line_order, column_order

```
`MyDB`.`MyTable` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `run_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `element_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `value` text,
  `line_order` int(11) default NULL,
  `column_order` int(11) default NULL
```

It is used to store data generated by a Java program that used to output this in CSV format, hence the line_order and column_order.
Lets say I have 4 entries (according to the table description):

```
1,1,'ELEMENT 1','A',0,0
2,1,'ELEMENT 2','B',0,1
3,1,'ELEMENT 1','C',1,0
4,1,'ELEMENT 2','D',1,1
```

I want to pivot this data in a view for reporting so that it would look like more like the CSV would, where the output would look this:

```
---------------------
|ELEMENT 1|ELEMENT 2| <--- Element Name
---------------------
|   A     |   B     | <--- Value From line_order = 0
---------------------
|   C     |   D     | <--- Value From line_order = 1
---------------------
```

The data coming in is extremely dynamic; it can be in any order, can be any of over 900 different elements, and the value could be anything. The Run ID ties them all together, and the line and column order basically let me know where the user wants that data to come back in order. I want it to sort/group by line and column order in the displayed matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with a self join:

```
select e1.element_name, e1.value, e2.value
from MyTable e1
inner join MyTable e2
on e1.element_name = e2.element_name
and e2.line_order = 1
where e1.line_order = 0
```

The from selects `line_order = 1`, the inner join selects `line_order = 2`.

Switch `inner join` to `cross join` if you'd like to return elements with only one line_order.

In reply to your comment, you could write out a fixed number of elements like:

```
select
    line_order
,   max(case when element_name = 'element 1' then value end) as Element1Value
,   max(case when element_name = 'element 2' then value end) as Element2Value
,   max(case when element_name = 'element 3' then value end) as Element3Value
,   ...
from MyTable
group by line_order
```

The `max()` construct assumes that `(element_name, line_order)` is unique.

Comment: Andomar, thank you for your help, but part of the problem is I don't know how many lines there will be. Sometimes line_order goes up to about 100, it can go to as many as 10,000

Comment: @manyxcxi: Sounds like you'd like to pivot an arbitrary number of columns.  Don't think there's a realistic way to do that in MySQL

Comment: What if I know the names of the elements I want, but don't know the number of lines? So the number of columns would be pre-set in the query... IE looking to pivot on element_name IN ('ELEMENT1','ELEMENT2','ELEMENT3')

Comment: @manyxcxi: You could perhaps group on line_order, example query added at end of answer

Comment: Thank you very much for your help- it is not the total answer to what I am trying to accomplish but you have put me very close to a solution I can use and in a much simpler fashion than how I was trying to solve it!